# SKProductsRequest returning 0 results

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storekit

Registered an IAP in iTunes Connect but the SKProductsRequestDelegate is returning empty results. Here is my request code:

```
let productID: Set = ["com.MyApp.MyApp.XXX.monthly"]
let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
request.delegate = self
request.start()
```

and here is my IAP in iTunes Connect:

[image]

Did I miss some sort of obvious step maybe (my bundle ID is definitely correct)?

**Edit**

Here is the screenshot of the product ID when you press "premium_200_30":

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot is not very informative. Does the content of the set match the `ProductID` as it appears when you press premium_200_30 ? Are you using a real device? (a simulator won't help here). And a suggestion: sometimes you can learn something by looking at the device logs from "Window">"Devices">"Your-device">"View Device Logs" (make sure to press the tiny triangle at the bottom)

Comment: What do you mean "Does the content of the set match the ProductID as it appears when you press premium_200_30"? Isn't the set supposed to only contain the product ID string?

Comment: The exact string to put there is the one revealed when you press the "premium_200_30" link of your screen shot. There you will see a "Product ID:" string. What about my other questions?

Comment: As you can see, the Product ID revealed when I press the premium_200_30 link is "monthly" - doesn't work. Yes using a real device.

Comment: Hi! sorry about missing the ProductID in the first screen.I'm using the ProductID as is without any prefix and it works for me. Just thinking aloud - maybe you need to submit it for approval (with the app!) before you can use it for the first time?

Comment: So you can't test until you've submitted it to the app store??